# "Cannot convert from string to double"

Tags: c#, string, math

Please can someone help me with the following problem. In the last line I get an error message stating that I

> cannot convert from string to double

It works though in the *first two lines*. Help will be much appreciated.

```
DeltaY.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(YCrd2.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(YCrd1.Text)).ToString();

DeltaX.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(XCrd2.Text) - Convert.ToDecimal(XCrd1.Text)).ToString();

Obs1Angle.Text = Math.Tan((Convert.ToDecimal(DeltaY.Text)) /
                          (Convert.ToDecimal(DeltaX.Text))).ToString();
```

Comment: Some of the textboxes do not have numbers in them. What are their values?

Comment: Math.Tan takes a double, not a decimal, consider changing Convert.ToDecimal to Convert.ToDouble

Comment: " I get an error message stating that I cannot convert from string to double." Are you sure that this is really the exact error message in the last line?

Comment: What are `YCrd2.Text`, `XCrd2.Text`, `DeltaY.Text` and `DeltaX.Text` values?

Comment: Side note: use `Math.Atan2` if `DeltaX.Text` can be `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to `Double` and do it once.

```
var deltaY = Convert.ToDouble(YCrd2.Text) - Convert.ToDouble(YCrd1.Text);
var deltaX = Convert.ToDouble(XCrd2.Text) - Convert.ToDouble(XCrd1.Text);

DeltaY.Text = deltaY.ToString();
DeltaX.Text = deltaX.ToString();

Obs1Angle.Text = Math.Tan(deltaY /deltaX).ToString();
```

Much neater code, no?

Alternatively, if you want to go for parsing, using C# 7.0...

```
if (double.TryParse(YCrd2.Text, out double yCrd2) &&
    double.TryParse(YCrd1.Text, out double yCrd1) &&
    double.TryParse(XCrd2.Text, out double xCrd2) &&
    double.TryParse(XCrd1.Text, out double xCrd1))
{
    var deltaY = yCrd2 - yCrd1;
    var deltaX = xCrd2 - xCrd1;

    DeltaY.Text = deltaY.ToString();
    DeltaX.Text = deltaX.ToString();

    Obs1Angle.Text = Math.Tan(deltaY /deltaX).ToString();
}
else
{
    // show error in string to double conversion
}
```

PS: As @DmitryBychenko notes in a comment, use `Math.Atan2` instead of `Math.Tan` if `DeltaX.Text` can be 0.

Comment: Thank you Mark, the short, neater code works perfectly and on the nose. Could you help clarify as to why the Math.ATan2 will not work, although the Math.Tan does? Thanks to all the other people for their suggestions.

Comment: You're welcome @TigerV. Please remember to mark the answer as useful and as the correct answer if you're happy with it.

I am not sure about the Math.Atan2 to be honest; I just rehashed what Dmitry Bychenko wrote earlier.

Answer (score 1):

In order to detect wrong format, you can try `TryParse` methods (`double.TryParse` in your case)

```
double y1 = 0;
double x1 = 0;
double y2 = 0;
double x2 = 0;

if (!double.TryParse(YCrd1.Text, out y1)) 
  Obs1Angle.Text = "Incorrect YCrd1 value";
else if (!double.TryParse(YCrd2.Text, out y2)) 
  Obs1Angle.Text = "Incorrect YCrd2 value";
else if (!double.TryParse(XCrd1.Text, out x1)) 
  Obs1Angle.Text = "Incorrect XCrd1 value";
else if (!double.TryParse(XCrd2.Text, out x2)) 
  Obs1Angle.Text = "Incorrect XCrd2 value";
else {
  // All values (x1, x2, y1, y2) are parsed
  DeltaX.Text = $"{x2 - x1}";
  DeltaY.Text = $"{y2 - y1}";

  //DONE: If you want to compute Angle, you want Arc function (ASin, ATan, ACos etc.)
  // Please, note, Atan2 - in case x2 - x1 == 0
  Obs1Angle.Text = $"{Math.Atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1)}";
}
```

Comment: the only one here who understood right away that OP actually wanted to calculate the angle and not the tangens :) @TigerV : you should mark this answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

When trying your code I get the error message:

> CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'decimal' to 'double'

If you look at the documentation of [Math.Tan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.tan?view=netframework-4.8) you will see that it takes a `double` as input parameter and not a decimal! So you need a different conversion:

EDIT: Furthermore you chose the wrong method. It looks like you want an angle as result. In this case you need to use the [Atan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.atan?view=netframework-4.8) method which takes as Parameter:

> A number representing a tangent.

and returns:

> An angle, θ, measured in radians, such that -π/2 ≤θ≤π/2.

```
Obs1Angle.Text = Math.Atan((Convert.ToDouble(DeltaY.Text)) / (Convert.ToDouble(DeltaX.Text))).ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering; The values for the textboxes are examples only, but I entered the following: YCrd2.Text = 1100, XCrd2.Text = 1100, YCrd1.Text = 1000, and XCrd1.Text = 1000. DeltaY.Text and DeltaX.Text is a result of the above as shown in the first two lines.

Comment: That is the exact message, and I tried Convert.ToDouble as well with no good results.

Comment: @TigerV " with no good results." what does that exactly mean?

Comment: @TigerV if the error message is really cannot convert **string** to double then I cannot reproduce your problem

Comment: @TigerV now I get it. You want to calculate the angle... in this case you are using the wrong method. Have a look at my edit. Or simply use and mark the answer by Dmitry as accepted.

Comment: thank you, I meant that it actually does not want to accept the To.Double", same as with the ToDecimal. I actually am busy making sense of the nonsense I was trying to do. Thanks again.

Comment: This problem is solved, and thank you to all who participated, I appreciate it. Forgive me if I make some mistakes when asking, and replying. I am new here, and finally have hope to finish what I am attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `TryParse` for preventing your string is not number.

```
decimal DeltaYVal, DeltaXVal;
if (decimal.TryParse(DeltaY.Text, out DeltaYVal) && decimal.TryParse(DeltaY.Text, out DeltaXVal))
{
                Obs1Angle.Text = Math.Tan(DeltaYVal / DeltaXVal).ToString();
}
```

Comment: `decimal` will not work here. Look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.tan?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thanks to all of you Guys for the help; I am still trying out, will be back asap. I appreciate your assistance.